# Manage answering support emails at a small business

Tags: open-source, email

I’m running a business together with two partners. Everyone of us may answer emails sent to the general support email address. But our current workflow is not optimal.

#### Our current workflow

Everyone of us is using a local email client with two IMAP mailboxes: the support account and a personal account.

1. A new email arrives at `support@example.com`, asking for support.
2. This email gets automatically forwarded to each of our personal mailboxes (`unor@example.com`, …) (to prevent that someone marks the email as read and the others don’t notice it)
3. We have to co-ordinate who of us will answer it (to prevent that more than one answer is sent).
4. One of us answers it (currently from his personal account).

#### Problems with this workflow

- Step 3 is cumbersome and takes too much time.
- Step 4: Everyone of us should be able to see/review *all* support emails, including answers (which are currently sent only to the personal account of one of us).

#### What we would like instead

- A system that shows & archives *all* support mails (sent + received), where all emails about the same topic should be grouped somehow.
- The ability to flag a new email somehow, indicating that the flagger is about to answer it.
- It would be nice if we could answer mails right from this system.

Requirements:

- Free/Libre Open Source Software
- OS:

  - If the solution is for desktops: it needs to be available cross-plattform (GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, Microsoft Windows)
  - If the solution is for servers: it needs to run on GNU/Linux
- We are not in local network, so it needs to work over the Internet.

Answer (score 6):

Since your question seems to be OK with web based: **Gmail**. Create one shared account everyone can use for support.

- GMail lets you view emails from 2 accounts simultaneously, one personal one support.
- You read and answer emails using shared account
- You can tag using either stars; OR using labels (including per-planned-answerer labels).
- Can answer right from the system
- Can see what was answered due to conversation threading view
- Can even see other people's drafts (as a bonus, can resume someone else's draft if needed since it's a shared account)
- Obviously works on Internet and is as cross platform as you can possibly get.
- Being a web browser, the client can be open-source (e.g. Firefox)
- While GMail is technically not open-source, it's 100% open data (you can export data from it 100% daily, in format compatible with any future email program).
- Bonus: Available on Android phones (again, can log in to multiple accounts)

---

**UPDATE:**

Since in the comments you identified that you are less interested in support **email** system and OK with ticketing one, the classic for that is [Request Tracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_Tracker) (aka RT).

- As any request tracking system, it's designed to have multiple users use a single support queue

  - Can assign tickets to a person when working on them (including reassign)
  - Can change ticket status
  - Can see the history of ticket responses in each ticket
  - Can manage ticket workflow status
- GPLv2 license
- Has email interface

  - Can pipe incoming emails to an email-to-RT gateway to turn them into RT tickets
  - Can subscribe to RT feed from individual accounts to know when tickets come in and are answered
  - Can even respond with emails to RT to post ticket responses.
- Has web front end

  - Can manage tickets, respond to tickets, and do full search of DB
- Has back-end DB so can do whatever advanced stuff you want with the support history data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12944/discussion-between-dvk-and-unor)

Answer (score 3):

[OSTicket](http://osticket.com/) is what we use currently. (We being [Efficito](http://www.efficito.com).)

It basically allows you to set up departments, have emails come in, and so forth.

One major disadvantage of Gmail is that if it is a shared account, then you have to change the password anytime someone leaves.  With OSTicket you can set up individual user accounts.  One thing I would recommend though is consider carefully how it works with email since we have found that we needed to plan out anti-spam measures to keep *us* from being spammed through it.

As a disclaimer, we are currently building a competing ticketing implementation which will use LedgerSMB as a back-end.

Comment: How would you flag an email (= *ticket*) so that it’s clear who will answer it? Can a user assign himself to a ticket? Or add a comment?

Comment: You can lock the ticket during response.   You can also post internal notes.  You can also assign it.